# How can I read data into a dynamically created tab in R Markdown?

Tags: r, for-loop, dynamic, r-markdown

I am creating a dynamic markdown document comprising a series of tabs with each tab named from the columns of a data frame. I want to pass data (the data from the data frame) to a plot function in each tab as it is generated.

I have been able to pass the data to the tab but it comes through as a single concatenated character string so I cannot plot it and cannot easily manipulate it to become numeric.

How do I pass the data through to the code in the tab so that I can work with it as numerical data?

I would greatly appreciate advice and suggestions.

I have tried variations on the code below but all seem to fall foul of how the data is being passed to the tab script (as single character string). This code produces the html document with the tabs and displays the data as a character string (e.g. chr “0.559-0.207-1.997-1.019-0.731-0.244-0.1290.653-0.7481.229”).

I have tried including *as.numeric* in the str(as.numeric('" etc but that did not work, resulting in "## Warning in str(as.numeric("-0.5890.4850.7450.450.0960.654-0.4910.922-0.3442.147")): NAs introduced by coercion"

I have tried various ways of creating a vector from each column in the data frame (e.g. "df <- as.vector(df[,'",title[i],"'])",'\n',) but that results in Error in df[, "one"] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable. I cannot subset a function but I do not see how to change what I am doing so that is not happening.

I am hoping to get the data that I pass to the tab to be numeric so I can plot it etc in each of the tab scripts.

````
#### generate dummy data
q1 <- data.frame(one = round(rnorm(10, 0, 1),3), two = round(rnorm(10, 0,1),3))

# Function to create multiple tabs, passes tab title and dataframe

make.tabs <- function(title, df){

  res <- NULL
  for(i in seq_along(title)){
    res <- c(res, '### ', title[i], '\n',
             
             "```{r, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}", '\n',
             
             "str('",df[,title[i]],"')", '\n',
             
             "#df <- c(",df[,title[i]],")", '\n',

             "#df <- as.vector(df[,'",title[i],"'])",'\n',
             
             "#df <- df[,'",title[i],"']",'\n',
            
             "#plot(df)",'\n',
             
             '```', '\n\n')
  }
  return(res)
}

# Create the Rmd to knit
cat(
  '---
title: "Dynamic data to plot"
author: "author"
date: "2030-10-23"
output: html_document
---

## Tabs {.tabset}


',
  make.tabs(title = c("one", "two"), df = q1),
  sep = "",
  file = "filetoknit.Rmd")

# Render the Rmd created into html here
rmarkdown::render("filetoknit.Rmd")
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my updated function definition of `make.tabs()`. It is a hacky workaround and I feel like R was not intended to be used this way. But it works.

The key is to use `deparse()` and force its evaluation on the spot (inside `c()` in the loop), using `eval()`.

Without `eval()`, it will be saved as an expression and only evaluated later when calling `cat()`. But this is too late, because it needs to be evaluated already when `cat()` is called to print it.

Hope this helps.

````
make.tabs <- function(title, df){
  
  res <- NULL
  for(i in seq_along(title)){
    res <- c(res, '### ', i, '\n',
             
             "```{r, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}", '\n',
             
             "data <- ", eval(deparse(df[i])), "\n",
             
             "plot(data)", "\n",
             
             '```', '\n\n')
  }
  return(res)
}
````

**Output**:

````
## Tabs {.tabset}


### 1
```{r, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}
data <- structure(list(one = c(1.335, 1.356, 0.929, -0.687, -0.837, -0.691, 1.197, -0.231, -0.436, -1.283)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
plot(data)
```

### 2
```{r, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}
data <- structure(list(two = c(-0.645, -1.25, 1.05, -2.534, 1.729, -0.863, 0.122, -0.264, 0.398, -0.66)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
plot(data)
```
````

Source:

The `deparse()` idea originates [here in a question how to print variable names in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62199865/r-print-name-of-object-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: This is great uke thank you. It works for me! I just needed to tweak the line:

"data <- ", eval(deparse(df[i])), "\n",

To be:

"data <- ", eval(deparse(df[,i])), "\n",

So the correct column was read. 

Thanks a million! I am unlikely to have stumbled onto deparse!